# Gulp less to css with Bitbucket Pipelines dont output files

Tags: gulp, less, bitbucket

i have following gulpfile.js:

```js
// including plugins
var gulp = require('gulp')
    , less = require("gulp-less");

// task
gulp.task('compile-less', function () {
    gulp.src('/less/*') // path to your file
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../Build/Productive/Less/'));
});
```

and following bitbucket pipelines configuration file:

```js
image: node:5.11.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm --version
          - npm install -g gulp
          - npm install gulp --save-dev
          - npm install gulp-less --save-dev
          - gulp compile-less
```

on my local machine the css file is outputtet in the right folder .. but when bitbucket pipelines runs the file is not generated :-)

any suggetions ?

Answer (score 0):

May want to try running NPM install as well. I noticed that I needed to install all of my required modules, and then grunt-cli globally and then grunt locally as well.

```
 - step:
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - npm install
        - npm install -g grunt-cli
        - npm install grunt --save-dev
        - grunt build
```

Might be similar with gulp.

Answer (score -2):

Probably way to late now but the solution for me was that bitbucket was case sensitive.

I had to use `git mv -f Styles.scss style.scss` to change the case and then it worked!